# Getting error when running sql server query in Python

Tags: python, sql-server, django, azure, pyodbc

I am building a web app using Django framework of Python , DB is Sql server Azure ,using Pyodbc.

I have an issue i am unable to resolve , i am getting a `parameter(file_name)` which is a string and when running the query with the parameter i am getting empty results in the first case and

```
  "sql = sql % tuple('?' * len(params))
            TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting"
```

in the 2nd case , what am i doing wrong?

```
file_name=request.POST.get('filetodelete')
    with connections['default'].cursor() as c:
       1st case
          parms=[file_name]
          sql='select *  from banks_row_data where file_name=%s'
          c.execute (sql,parms)
          test=c.fetchall()
      2nd case
          c.execute (sql,file_name)
          test=c.fetchall()
```

Comment: Why are you using raw SQL in Django, especially for such a trivial query?

Answer (score 4):

pyodbc uses `?` as the parameter placeholder, not `%s`.

```
sql = 'select *  from banks_row_data where file_name = ?'
```

Note though that since you are using Django you really should be using the Django model layer fur this kind of query.